# installation of ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso (which is a winRAR archive file)on Windows VISTA. Can I install Ubuntu along with Vista and if yes, how to install it from this winRAR file?

Answer (score 0):

Dual booting is simple. Just perform the steps as given below:

- Extract the WinRAR archive to obtain your `.iso` file
- Download *Universal USB Installer* software via `Google` and use it to create a bootable USB
- Once you have a bootable USB handy, click on `Windows` icon and search for `disk management`. Select the option `Create and format hard disk partitions`
- To install Ubuntu, take help of [dual boot Ubuntu and Windows](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) and ensure you perform the steps as given in that link
- Once you have installed Ubuntu (as per the steps given in the link), simply reboot your system and choose which OS you would like to boot into
- In case you are not presented with the option to choose OS on boot, then you need to setup your GRUB menu. To do so, proceed with the next set of steps:

**Steps to install GRUB**

- Again boot into `Windows` OS
- Combine `Windows` + `r` together and type `cmd` to open command prompt
- Type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit `Enter` key
- Reboot your system and then on every boot you will be presented with a proper GRUB menu to choose OS.

*P.S - You do not need to have admin rights on command prompt before you perform the above action.*